# ¿Cómo evitar que aparezca la pantalla de habilitar o inhabilitar las cookies en un WebView? Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, webview

Tengo un `WebView` enlazado enlazado a una página de wordpress, sucede que a veces muestra bien la información que debería aparecer, mostrando esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero muchas veces sale la siguiente pantalla, la cual es complicada quitar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo evitar que aparezca esa pantalla de habilitar o inhabilitar las cookies?

este el código que utilizo para enlazar el `WebView` a la página.

```
 browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.WVactualidad);
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    browser.loadUrl("http://facienapk.byethost7.com/?i=1");
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

No existe la forma de mostrar una pantalla para habilitar/deshabilitar cookies como en un navegador, en el caso de un `WebView` tienes que realizar esto programaticamente.

Para habilitarlas cookies primero tienes que configurar que las instancias de WebView de la aplicación pueden enviar y aceptar cookies mediante el método [setAcceptCookie()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setAcceptCookie(boolean)) o el método [setAcceptThirdPartyCookies()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(android.webkit.WebView,%20boolean)) para API 21+ o posterior.

> [setAcceptThirdPartyCookies()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(android.webkit.WebView,%20boolean))  Establece si WebView debe permitir
>   el establecimiento de cookies de terceros. Permitir cookies de
>   terceros es una política de WebView y se puede establecer de forma
>   diferente en diferentes instancias de WebView.

Ejemplo:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(myWebVIew, true);
    }else {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    }
```

al usar el valor false simplemente no permites el uso  de cookies.